# Баг в виджете QDateEdit 14 Sep 1752

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
auto edit = new QDateEdit{QDate{1000, 1, 1}, this};
```

Почему виджет показывает `14 Sep 1752` вместо ожидаемого `1 Jan 1000`? Как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Гениальный дизайн позволяет выставлять даты ранее 14 сентября 1752 только после вызова `setMinimumDate` с датой, меньшей этого числа. Задокументирована эта дата в 4 версии Qt, но не в 5 .